# Get length of arrays and last element of each array in angular of firestore data

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get length of arrays inside of the array.

```
let len = b.map((notess: Post) => notess.notes).length;
    // returning 4 
// eg- ['busy','not responding','later'] this array length should return 3
```

[image: This is the array from firestore]

Comment: Could you give a proper example with the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the `undefined` value, you can filter your array:

`myArray.filter(item => !!item).map(array => array.length)`

Comment: Thank you. Also I want to get last element , how can we do that

Answer (score 1):

```js
let list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], undefined];

let result = list.map((a) => Array.isArray(a) ? a.length : undefined);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, but i don't want these lengths again in array.

Comment: According to your question, this answer is correct, please update your question according to your needs